# Using R to find the proportion of winning

Tags: r

Setting a game:
Jack rolls a fair die 3 times, and if he rolls at least one six, he wins this game, otherwise he lose. Now I'm trying to simulate this game 100 times, to find the proportion of games that Jack would win.

```
t(replicate(100,sample(1:6, size = 3, replace = TRUE)))
```

I've simulated 100 games, but don't know how to figure out the proportion of winning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have:

```
s <- t(replicate(1000,sample(1:6, size = 3, replace = TRUE)))
```

What you need:

```
mean(rowSums(s == 6) > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
set.seed(1)
game <- as.data.frame(t(replicate(100,sample(1:6, size = 3, replace = TRUE))))
mean(apply(game, 1, FUN = function(x) any(x == 6)))
#> [1] 0.43
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
mean(
  replicate(1e3,{
    ifelse(max(sample(1:6, size = 3, replace = TRUE))==6,1,0)
  })
)
```

For this specific case you do not need simulations, it is equal to

```
1-(5/6)^3 = 0.4212963
```